# Force uv unwrap to obey seam

Tags: texturing, uv, edges

I have an extruded circle with a seam:

[image]

When I unwrap, the seem is not split. How can I force blender to split the UV map along the seam?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the UV editor after unwrapping?

Comment: Looks like the circle, with no split, I checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use follow active quads.
Select the faces next to the seam. then select all and unwrap using folow active quads.

[image]

Comment: Fixed my issue, but what happens if I still want it to be a disk? just with a split for whatever reason?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms If the circle is flat there will be no changes, to make a small gap where the seam is you will have to move one of the edges a bit higher or lower.